# ¿Como hacer para que R me devuelva una celda según una condición?

Tags: r, condiciones

Yo quiero que me devuelva el nombre de la provincia con la incidencia más alta. Es decir, necesito una condición en la que si se cumple que de la variable incidencia es el valor máximo, me devuelva el nombre de la celda de la variable PROVINCIA_RESIDENCIA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una forma es que ordenes el `data.frame` por `-incidencia` y te quedes con la primer observación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola!

Supongamos que tus datos se llaman `df`. Bastaría llamar a `df$PROVINCIA_RESIDENCIA[which.max(df$incidencia)]`